# Javascript Difference between normal function and function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypal-inheritance

In Javascript, the way to create classes (or objects) is to use;

```
function MyObj()
{
    this.someVar = "xyz";
    this.someMethod = function(){}
}
```

My simple question is how different is this function from a normal JavaScript function...say a function which adds 2 numbers?

Comment: This question is kind of vague. What do you mean exactly? In this function, you assign a value to a variable and call an other function outside your current function. If you add two numbers, you'll probably stay inside the function and won't call an other function. But I don't think that is your question..?

Comment: II would recommend reading the Article [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Comment: Do you mean difference between in-built functions and user-defined functions in javascript?

Comment: This [**`link`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) will help you to understand it better.

Answer (score 3):

The function aren't different. What makes the difference is how you call them.

For example, those have the same effect :

```
function MyObj(){
    this.someVar = "xyz";
    this.someMethod = function(){
        console.log(this.someVar);
    }
}
var obj = new MyObj();
obj.someMethod();
```

and

```
function someMethod(){
    console.log(this.someVar);
}
function MyObj(){
    this.someVar = "xyz";
}
var obj = new MyObj();
someMethod.call(obj);
```

and

```
function someMethod(){
    console.log(this.someVar);
}
function MyObj(){
    this.someVar = "xyz";
}
var obj = new MyObj();
obj.f = someMethod;
obj.f();
```

As you tagged your question [prototypal-inheritance](/questions/tagged/prototypal-inheritance), I'll complete by saying the best way to build your function would have been this one :

```
function MyObj(){
    this.someVar = "xyz";
}
MyObj.prototype.someMethod = function(){
    console.log(this.someVar);
}
var obj = new MyObj();
obj.someMethod();
```

This way, all instances of `MyObj` share the same function and thus are lighter.

Comment: they're not _quite_ the same - in the first version `someMethod` would have access to any other lexically scoped variables that are declared inside `MyObj`.  In the other versions the method doesn't share lexical scope so couldn't access them.

Comment: @Alnitak Right, but only if there are scoped variables.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is not so much in the contents of the function, but in how you call it.

If you call `var myObj = new MyObj()` then a new object is created.  By convention functions intended for use like this start with a capital letter.

If you were to call the function without the `new` keyword then exactly the same things happen inside the function, except that `this` will be the global object instead of the newly created object.  This wouldn't matter in a simple "add 2 numbers" function, but can cause very odd bugs if you forget it.

One way to ensure that it doesn't matter if you forget the `new` call is to put this in the top of your function:

```
function MyObj() {
     if (! (this instanceof MyObj)) {
         return new MyObj();
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: So, your function above make sure that `this` is referring to `MyObj()` but not global context. right?

Comment: @Mr_Green yes - if `new` was used then `this` is already a `MyObj` so the constructor continues as normal.  Otherwise the function returns the result of explicitly calling `new` on itself.

Comment: Ahh yes nice one :). Sorry I couln't understand it before.

Answer (score 1):

None. What matters is the use of the `new` keyword.

See here:

```
function Fun(){
    this.method = function(){
        return "Bar";
    }
    return "Foo";
}

var value = Fun(); // assigns the return value of Fun() to value
alert(value); // "Foo"
// alert(value.method()); // won't work because "Foo".method doesn't exist

var instance = new Fun(); // assigns a new instance of Fun() to instance
alert(instance); // [object Object]
alert(instance.method()); // "Bar"
```

Comment: nb: in your first example, you would actually have created `window.method` _instead of_ `value.method`.

Comment: that's puzzling - normally if you `return` some other value from a constructor then it replaces `this`, but that's not happening here.  Perhaps that rule only works if you return an object instead of a primitive?

Comment: RE: `window.method` being created in the first example - that's correct and an nice observation.

RE: a return object replacing this - that's correct too. And is a way to create singleton's in JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/5pFqd/